# Query AND and not OR using WHERE IN (list)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Considering I have three tables:

- product
- shop
- supplier

and their junction tables:

- product_shop
- product_supplier

I am trying to get all products that are supplied by a specific supplier and available in multiple shops, i.e. all products from supplier A that are in shop 1 and 2.

If we assume, supplier has 10 products, of which 5 are available in shop 1 and 7 are available in shop 2, but only 3 are available in shop 1 and 2, then those are the 3 I am seeking.

Here is what I have so far (in `postgresql 9.6`), which simulates an inclusive IN. Which works, but it doesn't seem right (proper) to me:

**edit:**
I use this query dynamically and have therefor to pass the list of shops (which varies), the supplier of course, and the count (which is equal to the length of the list of shops). It's not that this is a bother, but I was nonetheless wondering if there is a way to create a query using only joins.

```
 SELECT
    product_shop.product
FROM
    (SELECT product FROM product_shop where shop in (1, 2)) product_shop JOIN
    product_supplier ON product_shop.product = product_supplier.product 
WHERE
    product_supplier.supplier = A
GROUP BY
    product_shop.product
HAVING
    count(product_shop.product) = 2
```

Is there a better query to achieve the result I am seeking?

> *Not a native speaker

Comment: What do you mean "better query"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Having the count remove all duplicates is an extra step I would like to avoid if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will give you the desired result

```
SELECT product.* FROM product
    JOIN product_supplier ON product.id = product_supplier.productId
    JOIN product_shop ON product.id = product_shop.productId
WHERE product_shop.shopId  IN (1 , 2) 
    AND product_supplier.supplierId = 'A'
GROUP BY product.id
    HAVING COUNT(product.id) > 1
```

Its basically equivalent, but you do not need the subquery. There is, however, an error.
With your query you will only get the products that are available in exactly 2 shops.
since you wrote:

```
I am trying to get all products that are supplied by a specific supplier and available in multiple shops
```

Using `HAVING COUNT(product.id) > 1` would be more generic and correct.
However, it would not make any difference in this case, since you restricted the search to 2 shops.

I Also changed references like `product_supplier.supplier` to `product_supplier.supplierId`. You shroud use Id fields for table relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query with out Having the count

```
with cte_product -- fetching all the products which are in shop 1&2
(
   SELECT product,count(product) as cnt FROM product_shop 
    where shop in (1, 2) 
    group by product
)
SELECT * 
FROM
    cte_product psh
JOIN
    product_supplier psu 
ON psh.product = psu.product 
WHERE
    psu.supplier = A
and psh.cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Yes, recursiv is a good idea. However, using this particular query, I get a `42703 column does not exist` on psh.cnt

Comment: This query only works with 2 shops if I'm not mistaken. However, the length of the list of shops does vary.

Comment: From where you will get the list of shops? Do you need products from particular list of shops or do you need products which are in more than 1 shop

Comment: List of shops comes from the application side. I need all the products that that are in all the shops. Meaning, the list of shop varies (in content and length) and depending on that list, I need all the products that are in shop 1 AND 2 AND 3...

Comment: If possible load that list in temp table and join with product_shop table in CTE or else provide the application side code from where shop list are loading